# .htaccess | open file not directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Basically I have a directory setup like this:

```
/.htaccess
/home.php
/office.php
/office/tutorials.php
```

and a .htaccess file like this:

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
order deny,allow

# setup
DirectoryIndex /home.php
ErrorDocument 403 /err403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /err404.php

# remove trailing slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Now following is happening.
When I call "www.domain.com/home" it works perfectly.
But when I try to call "www.domain.com/office", I always get the home.php page without styling, and it shows i am at "www.domain.com/office/", so I guess in the directory named office.

I tried renaming the office/ directory, then the office.php file works perfectly again, but i need the directory to be named the same as the file, so the URI looks nice and clean and build up on each other like this:

```
www.domain.com/office (own page)
www.domain.com/office/tutorials (own page)
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3rd-to-last line reads:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

You've asked Apache not to map `www.domain.com/office` to `office.php` because there is a directly called `office`.  If that's not your desire, remove that line.

Comment: great! this solves most of the problem, but now it adds a slash at the end in the URI when there exists a directory with the same name as well...

Comment: If you want your "remove trailing slash" rule to apply to directories, then delete the same RewriteCond from that rule as well.